# AAD B2C authorized Web Api test with Postman fails

Tags: authentication, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to test a locally running web api authorized end point with Postman using AAD B2C with Microsoft account as identity provider.
The web api is running well, I can authenticate from client apps (Web App and UWP app), but I am not able to test it with Postman because can't get a token. Without authorization the Postman works well.

I am using the following guideline:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-3.0

The Postman's error message:
[image]

Postman's settings:
[image]

AAD B2C Applications:

[image]

AAD B2C Postman App properties:
[image]

AAD B2C Postman App API access:
[image]

Can you tell me any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro your issue. Based on your capture, the `Auth URL` in postman setting(pic 2) , the host you are using is `https://login.microsoftonline.com` which will cause redirect uri issue while using MSA identity provider.

To solve this issue , you should use this host: `https://{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com`.

Details see [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) :

> When you set up an identity provider for sign-up and sign-in in your
>   Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) application, you need to
>   specify a redirect URL. You should no longer reference
>   login.microsoftonline.com in your applications and APIs. Instead, use
>   b2clogin.com for all new applications, and migrate existing
>   applications from login.microsoftonline.com to b2clogin.com.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Thank you, the idea to change to the b2clogin.com format helped.

But none of the examples are working for me in the MS docs.

Finally using the same end point as in the UWP project is made it work:

h ttps://b2ctest.b2clogin.com/tfp/b2ctest.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

Comment: Hi @IstvánPiroska , glad to know that it helps . Pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark this answer so that it will help others who has the same issue . If you have any further concerns , pls post a new one and I'll try to solve it once I see it . Thanks !